# Do you understand a sentence like this?

Tags: grammar

> I have waited for my favorite time period of in the evening.

Can this sentence make sense in meaning?

Comment: Are you trying to construct sentences which use apposition? *I have waited for my favorite time of day, the evening.*

Comment: You have asked 10 questions within the past day, almost all of which ask if something is an apposition. We don't offer this kind of help, because they are all essentially repetitions of the same question. Please search online for "apposition" and study the many examples you will find.

Answer (score 0):

We can understand it, but it's not idiomatic. The major problem comes from the adjacent  **of** and **in**.

You are using **in the evening** as a time period, **evening** is sufficient. You then get

> I have waited for my favorite time period of evening.

However, this also feels clumsy, **time period** could be replaced by **time of day**, we then also remove the unnecessary preposition

> I have waited for my favorite time of day (of) evening.
>
> I have waited for my favorite time of day, evening.

Or perhaps better:

> I have waited for evening, my favourite time of day.